# TFS 2008 workspace deletion disaster

Tags: visual-studio-2008

This morning I opened VS2008 and connected to TFS. Being the start of a new year, I decided to do a bit of cleanup. First up was to remove any unused workspaces I had (namely, a workspace that was still present from my old dev workstation which I've long since moved off of).

So, I went to File->Source Control->Workspaces, and selected the workspace I wanted to get rid of, and then pressed the remove button. I got a warning that any pending changes on my local machine would be lost. As I had no changes pending, I proceeded with the delete.

After that, neither I, nor anyone else on the team could see any source in TFS. They lost their mappings; and with the exception of any files they had checked out... they no longer had access to any files under TFS control; the various project branches simply no longer appeared under Source Control in the team explorer pane; it was as if me removing my workspace deleted all workspaces for the entire team. The TFS admin was able to see the various branches OK, and (I may not be using the right terms here) - but he found that if he created a new "group", removed the users from the old "group", and then added them to the new "group", people could once again see their source code. Regardless, the decision was made to recover from backup.

I'm obviously by no means a TFS admin, but I'd always thought of a workspace as a mapping between TFS and my workstation, and if I were to remove a workspace, it would simply mean that I could reconnect to TFS, re map to my local drive, do a get latest and go back to work.

Unfortunately in this case I shut the whole team down as we wait for the sys admins to recover the TFS repository from backup.

Do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the concept of workspaces, or perhaps there is some configuration setting somewhere that shouldn't be set the way it is, or ....?

I've searched the web quite a bit, but everything I found led me to believe that the removal of a workspace was not a huge deal, and wouldn't have any impact on the rest of the team.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

As googling has pointed out, the removal of a TFS workspace is *not* a huge deal, and won't have any impact on the rest of the team.  I have no explanation for the behavior you saw - and unless you kept the log files before restoring from backup - it will be impossible to diagnose.

The symptoms you point to do *not* reflect a change in workspaces, however, but a change in *permissions*.  Your users lacking visibility into the source tree in Source Control Explorer suggests that they lack read permissions on the source tree.

My best guess is that a TFS administrator accidentally removed read permissions for a group of users, or an Active Directory administrator removed users from an AD group, and that this is completely unrelated to your workspace deletion.

Comment: Thanks Edward - I could see how that might be possible, unfortunately the TFS admin sits next to me, and this all happened before he got in. Also, I could see everything in TFS _before_ I deleted the workspace. Finally, (and I should have mentioned this earlier) there are other branches that are still visible to the rest of the team; these branches are at the same "level" that the one that has dissapeared, IOW the only branches that dissapeared were ones that my workspace was mapped to.

Answer (score 0):

kindly checked your permissions . i think that it is an issue in permission so that nobody can see project and every thing.

add peoples(as you requirement or developers) to contributor in Team Project Collection Setting.

`important note` : kindly add them to Team Project Collection Setting(contributor) and then add again in Team Project Setting(contributor).

then see the change. after that you can manage your permissions as you want!!!